# Django admin without template context processor

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to make django-admin interface not to include some of the template context processors?

in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   ..some.django.context.processors,
   'myapp.views.context_processor',
)
```

in my.views.py:

```
def context_processor(request):
    return {'user': my_custom_string}
```

So, data returning in 'my' context_processor overrides 'user' variable in django-admin template context and i've got an error.

And the second problem is that 'my' context_processor returnes 'fat' dict. There is no need to have it in admin's interface

Answer (score 0):

You have the request object available to your context processor; you can examine the request's `path` to see if it's under the root path of the admin.

Comment: Thank you. Thought about this, in my opinion its not so clear

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to interpret that. If you mean you aren't sure how to check that path, something like `if not request.path.startswith('/admin/'): ...` (where you should change that string if you use a different URL for your admin interface).